# D3 line graph not showing in windows firefox but works in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Below line graphs are not showing in firefox in windows but works in ubuntu firefox and chrome also. If you run this code in windows firefox lines will not show. Red and blue lines are i'm expecting to be visible in the below graph.

```js
var n = 120;//number of seconds to be seen on chart / duration  (120 means 10mt(600sec) chart for duration = 5sec)
var clientsArray ={"grid_ar":[{"c":"grey","t":2000,"i":"NA","ul":" ","dl":" ","ulv":"400.0","dlv":"100.0","st":"CONNECTED","ssid":"NA","bssid":"NA","rssi":"NA","ipv6":"NA"},{"c":"grey","t":2001,"i":"NA","ul":"","dl":"","ulv":"0.0","dlv":"0.0","st":"CONNECTED","ssid":"NA","bssid":"NA","rssi":"NA","ipv6":"NA"},
{"c":"grey","t":2002,"i":"NA","ul":"","dl":"","ulv":"20.0","dlv":"0.0","st":"CONNECTED","ssid":"NA","bssid":"NA","rssi":"NA","ipv6":"NA"}]};

var chartWidth = 500;
var clientWidth = 37.5;
var chartHeight = 175;
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
 .append('svg:svg')
 .attr('width', chartWidth)
 .style("border-style", "none")
 .attr('height', chartHeight);
  
    duration =2000, //update interval in msec
    now = new Date(Date.now() - duration),
    data1 = d3.range(n).map(function() { return 0; });
    data2 = d3.range(n).map(function() { return 0; });
    data3 = d3.range(n).map(function() { return 0; });
    
var trendWidth = chartWidth*1.0-clientWidth*0.5 ;
var trendHeight = chartWidth*0.3;
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([now - (n - 1) * duration, now - 0*duration])
    .range([0, trendWidth]);

var y1 = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 400])
    .range([trendHeight, 0]);

var y2 = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 400])
    .range([trendHeight, 0]);

var y3 = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 3])
    .range([trendHeight, 0]);

var line1 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y1(d); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y2(d); });

var line3 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y3(d); });

var area3 = d3.svg.area()
  .interpolate('monotone')
  .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration);})
  .y(function(d, i) { return y3(d);})
  .y0(trendHeight*1)

var xaxis1 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(clientWidth*0.5)+"," + (chartHeight) + ")")
    .attr("font-size", function(d,i) { return clientWidth*0.2+"px";})
    .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

var y12axis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y12 axis")
    .attr("font-size", function(d,i) { return clientWidth*0.2+"px";})
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(trendWidth+clientWidth*0.5)+"," + (chartHeight*0.995-trendHeight) + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y1).orient("right"));

var y3axis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y3 axis")
    .attr("font-size", function(d,i) { return clientWidth*0.2+"px";})
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(trendWidth+clientWidth*1.2)+"," + (chartHeight*0.995-trendHeight) + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y3).orient("right"));

var path1 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip1)")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(clientWidth*0.25)+"," + (chartHeight-trendHeight) + ")")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data1)
    .attr("class", "line1")
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("d", line1);
var path2 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip2)")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(clientWidth*0.25)+"," + (chartHeight-trendHeight) + ")")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data2)
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("d", line2);
var path3 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip3)")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(clientWidth*0.25)+"," + (chartHeight-trendHeight) + ")")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data3)
    .attr("class", "line3")
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("d", line3)

var path4 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(clientWidth*0.25)+"," + (chartHeight-trendHeight) + ")")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data3)
    .attr("class", "area3")
    .attr('fill', 'green')
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.3)
    .attr("d", area3);

var transition = d3.select({}).transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear");

(function tick() {
  transition = transition.each(function() {

    //console.log("x");
    // update the domains
    now = new Date();
    x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);

    // Taking some dummy data; here we need to call server
    var dltSum = 0;
    var ultSum = 0;
    var conClSum = 0;
    
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
       if(clientsArray.grid_ar[i].st == "CONNECTED") {
          conClSum = conClSum + 1;
   ultSum=ultSum+parseFloat(clientsArray.grid_ar[i].ulv);
   dltSum=dltSum+parseFloat(clientsArray.grid_ar[i].dlv);
       }
    }

    //data1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101));
    //data2.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101));
    //data3.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 257));
    data1.push(dltSum);
    data2.push(ultSum);
    data3.push(conClSum);

    // redraw the line
    svg.select(".line1")
        .attr("d", line1)
        .attr("transform", null);

    svg.select(".line2")
        .attr("d", line2)
        .attr("transform", null);

    svg.select(".line3")
        .attr("d", line3)
        .attr("transform", null);

    svg.select(".area3")
        .attr("d", area3)
        .attr("transform", null);

    // slide the x-axis left
    xaxis1.call(x.axis);
    //xaxis2.call(x.axis);
    //xaxis3.call(x.axis);

    // slide the line left
    path1.transition()
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ",0)");

    path2.transition()
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ",0)");

    path3.transition()
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ",0)");

    path4.transition()
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ",0)");

    // pop the old data point off the front
    data1.shift();
    data2.shift();
    data3.shift();

  }).transition().each("start", tick);
})();
```

```css
.line1 {
           fill: none;
           stroke-width: 1px;
       }

       .line2 {
           fill: none;
           stroke-width: 1px;
       }

       .line3 {
           fill: none;
           stroke-width: 1px;
       }

       .axis path,
       .axis line {
           fill: none;
           stroke: #000;
           shape-rendering: crispEdges;
       }

       .axis path,
       .axis line,
       .axis1 path,
       .axis1 line {
           fill: none;
           stroke: #E6E7E8;
           shape-rendering: crispEdges;
       }
       .brush .extent {
         stroke: #FFF;
         shape-rendering: crispEdges;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Chrome: [image]
Firefox: [image]

What might be the problem here? any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you turn this into a stack snipet so we can run it?

Comment: i updated my question with working code please check now

Comment: It's working for me: Windows 7 64bits with Firefox 45.

Comment: i tested on windows 8 64 bit Firefox 53 & 54. not working

Comment: I had the same problem - my `urls` for `clip-path` were wrong and it still worked on chrome but not on firefox (I had two `#` by accident).  So maybe check to make sure your url line ids are correct (`.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip3)")`)